# Break Complex/Compound Sentences into Simple Sentences using NLP

Tags: python, nlp, stanford-nlp, grammar, spacy-3

I want to break sentences i.e complex/compound sentences, the sentences that are larger in size and consist of more than two sentences.

for eg: I like to eat apples but I hate apple juice.
Here the sentence has two sentences in it, "I like to eat apples" and "I hate apple juice."
I want to break them.

I parsed it with spacy and break it on conjunction part, that is simple but I want to break more complex sentences that are not connected with conjunction like:

1. Though Mitchell prefers watching romantic films, he rented the latest spy thriller,
   and he enjoyed it very much.
   should be breaked in three sentences: Though Mitchell prefers watching romantic films ::: he rented the latest spy thriller ::: he enjoyed it very much.

Similarly,
2. The team captain jumped for joy, and the fans cheered because we won the state
championship.
should break in: The team captain jumped for joy :: the fans cheered :: because we won the state.

Is there any library in nltk or spacy or any other nlp framework to do that logical splitting of sentences. I also tried spacy sentencizer but that seems to work only on setting sentence boundaries. Any help would really appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to best transform a syntactically complex into a syntactically simple text with python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72462836/how-to-best-transform-a-syntactically-complex-into-a-syntactically-simple-text-w)

Comment: Umm.. No, he was asking to add some meaning to extracted sentences, but in my case I just want to break the sentence, so that I can apply some functions to it as my algorithm needs small sentences, so I just want to split complex sentences into meaningful sentences, hence my purpose is different. and I think that can be possible to break sentence grammatically ??

Comment: Did you make any progress with this issue? I am also interested and have the same doubts